# Next.js link doesn't render with page scrolled at the top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component like so:

```
const Milestone = props => {
  const { path, disabled, index, ...rest } = props;

  if (disabled) return <MilestoneCheck disabled />;

  return (
    <Link href={path} passHref>
      <a>
        <MilestoneCheck {...rest} />
      </a>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

when I click on the 'Link' to go to the next page and than click the back button to go back to where I came from, the page doesn't load at the top but from the last scrolled position. 
Adding a 'scrollTop' method on route change would feel not very efficient, is there a more elegant solution to always having the page loading at the top?

Comment: Have a look on this GitHub issue solution https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28778#issuecomment-1017435267

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ended up doing this in the main app.js file:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
      window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's the answer!

Answer (score 16):

I had this experience and I tried a lot of ways to get it to work but it didn't.
This kind of route change behavior is supposed to happen by default except you're doing something different.

I noticed that after I removed `overflow-x: hidden` from my `html/body` tag everything started to work normally.

Try not to use this form of styling in your html/body element:

```
html, body {
- overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You can set a wrapper element's (i.e `div`) maximum width to `100vw` and `overflow-x:hidden` to archive the same thing.

Comment: Thanks bro, I was exploring this error for 1 day, and finally I got here and saw your answer. It helped me and saved my next day. I am shocked that this one line ruined my life for 1 day.

Comment: @Abidullah I'm glad you found it useful. :)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue when my page would not render at the top.  In my case in my `global.css` i had this:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

After removing `scroll-behavior: smooth;` everything started working as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution.Tried many things to resolve this issue. Finally, this worked very silly of us.

Comment: This was definitely the issue in my case. Thanks. What alternative can one use for smooth scrolling then?

Answer (score 6):

A possible cause could be `overflow-x: hidden;` on one of the root elements: `body`, `html` or `#__next`.

You can try to add `min-height: 100%` to it or replace it with `overflow-x: clip;`.

Comment: add overflow-x: clip fixed my issue. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this issue for a few days and found the solution.

The issue for some unknown reason was that NextJS has some bug when a global html style is imported. I had html class in my global styles.scss import that was loaded into my main wrapper.  Once I removed the html from the import the scrolling issues stopped and pages loaded as they would on a static site.

Found the solution here https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7594

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using Bootstrap and I had to remove in the bootstrap.min.css file:

```
:root {
 scroll-behavior: 'smooth'
}
```

Comment: You're right! I had to edit bootstrap.min.css and that solved my problem!

Answer (score 3):

Another reason pages are not scrolled to the top upon navigation is when the following style rule exists:

`html { height: 100%; }`

There is a Github issue on this [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28778).

Comment: I was scratching my head on this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

inside of your Page/Layout component import next router

```js
import Router from 'next/router';

// you can then hook into there events

Router.onRouteChangeStart = () => {

};

Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => {
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  });
};

Router.onRouteChangeError = () => {

};

const Page = props => { 
  return <div>{props.children}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `top: 0` works with `behavior: 'smooth`, but **not** with `behavior: 'auto'`. With default  `behavior: 'auto'` value `top: 0` **not** working, but any other values work e.g:

```
window.scroll({
  top: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me (updated to newest NextJS routing configuration)

```
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', (url) => {
      window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change next configuration scrollRestoration to false.

experimental: {
scrollRestoration: false
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Next.js 13 with app router.

The fix for me was changing my wrapper element from:

```
<>
// your code
</>
```

to

```
<div>
</div>
```

Very annoying to find but this little fix worked for me.

Answer (score -7):

Wrap your App component with:

```
<ScrollToTop>
  ... all components there
</ScrollTop>
```

ScrollTop component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const ScrollToTop = ({ children, location: { pathname, search } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // just a fallback for older browsers
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }, [pathname, search]);

  return children;
};

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

Comment: The question was about Next.js. You are suggesting using `react-router`.